# Overlay Strings In Java While Skipping Spaces

Tags: java, string, methods

I want to overlay two strings together in Java to make one string. I already have a method to do something like this, but not exactly what I want.

For example, if I tell it to overlay `"Hello World"` with `"     Hi"`, I will get `"     Hiorld"`.

I want to be able to overlay `"Hello World"` with `"     Hi"`, and get `"HelloHiorld"`!

Here is the method I currently am using:

```
public static String overlayString(String str, String overlay, int start, int end) {
          if (str == null) {
              return null;
          }
          if (overlay == null) {
              overlay = "";
          }
          int len = str.length();
          if (start < 0) {
              start = 0;
          }
          if (start > len) {
              start = len;
          }
          if (end < 0) {
              end = 0;
          }
          if (end > len) {
              end = len;
          }
          if (start > end) {
              int temp = start;
              start = end;
              end = temp;
          }
          return new StringBuffer(len + start - end + overlay.length() + 1)
              .append(str.substring(0, start))
              .append(overlay)
              .append(str.substring(end))
              .toString();
      }
```

How would this method look if I wanted the method to avoid replacing characters with spaces, but still keep the positioning of the text?

Comment: You might need to switch over to logic that steps through both strings character by character, skipping chars in the overlay string if they are whitespace.

Comment: Even though I really don't want to do the work of writing a method with that logic, I will probably have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can thing of two ways you might be able to achieve something like this...

First...

```
public static String overlay1(String value, String with) {
    String result = null;
    if (value.length() != with.length()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The two String's must be the same length");
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);
        for (int index = 0; index < value.length(); index++) {
            char c = with.charAt(index);
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                sb.setCharAt(index, c);
            }
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which allows you to pass to `String`s of the same length and will replace all the "non-whitespace" content of the second in the first, something like...

```
overlay1("Hello World", 
         "      Hi   "));
```

Or you could specify the location you want the `String` to be overlaied, for example...

```
public static String overlay2(String value, String with, int at) {
    String result = null;
    if (at >= value.length()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insert point is beyond length of original String");
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);
        // Assuming a straight replacement with out needing to 
        // check for white spaces...otherwise you can use
        // the same type of loop from the first example
        sb.replace(at, with.length(), with);
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    return result;
}

overlay2("Hello World", 
         "Hi", 
         5));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! (I am going to edit and use the first solution.) The only downside to the first method is that they have to be the same length, but I can work around that by adding spaces if they aren't the same length.

Comment: @JohnDoe That was my restriction, you "could" merge the two ideas, providing a "start" point for the `for-loop` to start at, but that comes down to your needs ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could put the first `String` into a `StringBuffer`, use a loop to check which characters in the second `String` are not spaces, then use the StringBuffer's `.replace()` method to replace these characters.

For example,

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Hello World");
sb.replace(5, 7, "Hi");
```

gives `"HelloHiorld"`

Comment: Can I have an example, please? I think I know how to go about doing this but I am not too sure about it.